# New issue - runtime error - Out of Memory

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting an error as Runtime error 7 while running the cleanup names utility as mentioned in code below. I am using 512 GB HDD, 8 GB RAM, I7 processor so should not be a memory issue and still the issue pops up.

My workbook has 123188 defined names which I want to delete using the code below. Is there a way to be more efficient with the code / does someone has a code / built in addin which I can incorporate in a master addin?

The function breaks at

> For Each objName In ActiveWorkbook.Names

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

```
    Option Explicit

Sub Cleanup_names123()
'
'Deletes all names except for Print_Area, Database, and DB

'Declare variables
Dim objName As Name
Dim strAnswer As String

'Display instructions
strAnswer = MsgBox("This function will delete all named ranges except Print_Area, DB, and Database. If you are not ready to proceed click Cancel to exit.", vbOKCancel)
'If cancelled - exit function
If strAnswer = vbCancel Then End

'If no names found, exit
If ActiveWorkbook.Names.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No names found. Macro complete."
    End
End If

MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Names.Count & " name(s) found. It may take a few minutes for the cleanup."

'Delete names
For Each objName In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    On Error Resume Next
    If InStr(objName.Name, "Database") <> 0 Then
        'If Database - no action
    ElseIf InStr(objName.Name, "database") <> 0 Then
        'If database - no action
    ElseIf InStr(objName.Name, "DB") <> 0 Then
        'If database - no action
    Else
        objName.Delete
        ThisWorkbook.Names(objName.Name).Delete
    End If
Next

On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: From what I have googled so far, it mentions that since it has to loop through a lot of names it might be inefficient and may crash as well. An alternative that google suggests is to store names in an array and then delete it at once. Any suggestions if that is good idea and how can that be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If iterating the collection is taking up too much memory you can manually select each item one by one. When deleting items it's important to work backwards from the end because when you delete item 1 then item 2 becomes item 1. So we use `Step -1` to work backwards.

To make your guard clause read plainly and avoid empty Ifs I changed the logic to `If Not And`. I find this more clear. Don't use underscore `_` in method names because that is reserved for Event methods.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CleanupNames()
    '
    'Deletes all names except for Print_Area, Database, and DB

    'Declare variables
    Dim strAnswer As String

    'Display instructions
    strAnswer = MsgBox("This function will delete all named ranges except Print_Area, DB, and Database. If you are not ready to proceed click Cancel to exit.", vbOKCancel)
    'If cancelled - exit function
    If strAnswer = vbCancel Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim NamesCount As Long
    NamesCount = ActiveWorkbook.Names.Count
    
    'If no names found, exit
    If NamesCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No names found. Macro complete."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    MsgBox NamesCount & " name(s) found. It may take a few minutes for the cleanup."

    'Delete names
    Dim iter As Long
    For iter = NamesCount To 1 Step -1
        Dim objName As String
        objName = ActiveWorkbook.Names.Item(iter).Name
        
        On Error Resume Next
        If Not InStr(objName, "Database") <> 0 And _
           Not InStr(objName, "database") <> 0 And _
           Not InStr(objName, "DB") <> 0 Then
           
            ActiveWorkbook.Names(objName).Delete
        End If
        
        If iter Mod 5000 = 0 Then ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Next iter
End Sub
```

UPDATE: Added the save code and changed the delete behavior.

Comment: thank you for modifying the code. I ran the code and it is now working. A quick question, the code deleted 16473 names in an hour. Is it supposed to be that slow?  My filesize is just 5MB and I am using 64 bit version too. I ask this as the code may crash if it keeps running too long. By any chance, can we add a feature that after every maybe 5k names deletion, the code saves the file and re runs to avoid crash?

Comment: Inside the for loop, use Mod (modules). If Iter Mod 5000 = 0 Then ActiveWorkbook.Save

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. I tried but failed. Can you help repost the code in here so that I can copy the code. Also just to reconfirm, should deletion of names ranges be such a slow task?

Comment: I changed the code to use just the name as a string instead of an object. This might speed it up a bit. I also added the code to save every 5000 records and the will certainly slow it down a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. The approach I took was to run a loop backwards from the bottom so that excel doesn't move the items up each time one is deleted and deleting via Index number rather than name. I also made the test a little more efficient I think.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteNames()

Dim NameCount As Long
Dim Cntr      As Long
Dim WkBk      As Workbook
Dim TestName  As String

Set WkBk = ThisWorkbook

NameCount = ActiveWorkbook.Names.Count

'Delete names

With WkBk

  For Cntr = NameCount To 1 Step -1
  
     On Error Resume Next  'not sure you need this but can't hurt
    
     TestName = UCase(.Names(Cntr).NameLocal)
      If InStr(TestName, "DATABASE") > 0 Or _
         InStr(TestName, "DB") > 0 Then
          'If database - no action
      Else
        .Names(Cntr).Delete
      End If
    
  Next Cntr

End With 'WkBk

End Sub
```

HTH

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the code. I tried this as well in the workbook I have and it appears to have the same speed as the previous one.  (Though it works).  It it true that the code deletes `300 names per minute? As in that case deleting names will take a lot of time. I have more than 125000 names in my workbook

Answer (score 0):

It may be as simple as turning off calculation and screen updates... this should increase stability and greatly increase speed.

So, before your For...Next loop -

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

Then after your For...Next loop -

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

You should also consider running those last two lines after trapping any errors so that you don't leave the settings inactive.

Comment: I doubt this will help with an error that is memory-related.

Comment: @dwirony, xlCalculationManual is a time-worn, proven method of helping with out-of-memory errors in Excel. It's certainly worth a shot. I was going to post a link but there are so many.

Comment: I read this approach somewhere else too but it did not work for some reason. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the extra bit about saving you asked for. I haven't coded up your solution as you should be able to modify this accordingly.  This counts backwards from 50 and saves every 5 times through the loop with a debug statement so you can see that it works.

```
Sub quickSaveDemo()

Dim counter As Integer
counter = 50

For i = counter To 1 Step -1
    Debug.Print "Loop count - " & i & " - Other stuff here"
    If i Mod 5 = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Save here"
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```